# Object check on non existing variable for document check

Tags: javascript, selenium, extjs

I have a one liner Js for Selenium tests that checks if the page is done loading.

```
true  === ((typeof Ext.Ajax != 'undefined' && Ext.Ajax.isLoading()) || (jQuery != 'undefined' && jQuery.active) || document.readyState != 'complete')
```

All other Java/Selenium ways to check are **NOT** compatible with our setup line of IE FF and Chrome tests (crap IE). We spent like 3 months of trying, so Selenium checks are out of question. 
This check is ok most of the time, except when the Extjs variable is not set in that page then i get the dreaded Ext is not defined exception and selenium crashes. 
Is there an another way to check for a variable in one liner which can do nested checks i tried object checks like in

[javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

But when i do

> ((Ext|| {}).Ajax

I still get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As I have read the rest of the posts I have come across a solution:

```
(typeof Ext != 'undefined' ? Ext : {})
```

Answer (score 1):

This also should work:

```
(window.Ext || {}).Ajax
```